# Integrating with a 'presentation clicker' (OS X)

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

My (OS X Cocoa) app has a 'presentation mode'. I want people to be able to use those presentation clickers that provide next/back buttons (as supported by Keynotes and Powerpoint)

Does anyone know how this is done in a Mac Cocoa app? Are the next/back clicks presented as simple mouse clicks or what?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FN+PageUp and FN+PageDown keypresses are sent (from a Kingston clicker at least.)